LazyVGrid block align
Does anyone know how to achieve this in SwiftUI?

LazyVGrid seems a bit too lazy: it just resizes the height of a row, but doesn't attempt to fit stuff from below.

I want to draw an array if items dynamically in a grid. It could be something like [bsb] or [bbbbbbbssbb] or [sssssssssssb]... just anything (where b = big and s = small)
Thanks ahead

With a Grid you can have the cells in a row span multiple columns, but I don't think there is any kind of grid that allows cells to span multiple rows. If you will only ever want the cells to span multiple rows and never to span multiple columns then you could build a Grid sideways and then rotate it by 90 degrees, but that is getty pretty messy. Otherwise, you can just build up the view using a combination of HStack and VStack.

" but that is getty pretty messy." how messy would that be? What can I expect? Scrolling, resizing issues, I guess

For plain colors it's fine. But when you start having content like Text, you will have to rotate the text in the opposite direction, so that it is back to normal after the grid has been rotated.

You are so right. Thanks for pointing out. I will try the HStack and VStack approach.

You can give a try to UICollectionView by wrapping in SwiftUI view representable: https://gist.github.com/satishVekariya/eb72196e4289eb7b20a32d2b68afa7ee
